# How to use category_filter in java for yelp

Tags: android, yelp

Please kindly tell me how to use category_filter in search results for yelp API call in java. I have used Oauth to make request parameter. In this code, how can i add parameter for category_filter

```
private static final String API_HOST = "api.yelp.com";
static  String DEFAULT_LOCATION = "London"; 
private static final int SEARCH_LIMIT = 20;
private static final String SEARCH_PATH = "/v2/search";
private static final String BUSINESS_PATH = "/v2/business";



request =new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://" + API_HOST + SEARCH_PATH);
        request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.TIMESTAMP, seconds.toString());
        request.addHeader(OAuthConstants.TIMESTAMP, seconds.toString());
        request.addQuerystringParameter("term", DEFAULT_TERM);
        request.addQuerystringParameter("location", DEFAULT_LOCATION);
        request.addQuerystringParameter("limit", String.valueOf(SEARCH_LIMIT));
```